# pd.read_csv Weird letter 'u' appearing

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

Hi I'm reading a file using

```
headers1 = pd.read_csv(file1, nrows=1).columns
```

This works well but the letter **'u'** is appearing before every column header? It's definitely not in the original file. Any ideas where it came from or how I can get rid of it?

I'm guessing this means it's in unicode. I've tried to encode this to latin-1 but to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
Index([u'tLap', u'sLap', u'NLap', u'vCar'
```

Above is an example of the printed code before attempts to encode

```
headers1 = pd.read_csv(file1, nrows=1).columns
headers1.encode('latin-1')
print headers1
```

response

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it? It most probably just means that its a unicode literal. You should also show what exactly you mean by the`u` appearing ( as an example) .

Comment: This may be my ignorance playing through but will it not affect my future code? The next step for me is to iterate through the headers into a matplotlib graph with the parameters in the rest of the csv file

Comment: You can ignore this it's not going to print you column labels with a `u` prefix

Comment: Oh really? All this fuss I'm making over nothing.... thanks guys!

Comment: and `headers1` in this case is not a string here, so has no `encode` method, hence the error message you're seeing.

Comment: I think `headers1 = headers1.str.encode('latin-1')` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore this, it just means the strings are unicode literals, they will not display with a `u` prefix when you pass them as labels for plotting.

With respect to the error, `headers1` is a `Pandas.Index` object, if you want to encode them call the vectorised [`str.encode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.encode.html#pandas.Series.str.encode) method:

```
headers1.str.encode('latin-1')
```

but really this is unnecessary